# Selecting single directory that satisfies certain pattern

Tags: bash, shell, directory

I would like to be able to get name of the first directory that matches a certain pattern, say:

```
~/dir-a/dir-b/dir-*
```

That is, if the directory `dir-b` contained directories `dir-1`, `dir-2`, and `dir-3`, I would get `dir-1` (or, alternatively, `dir-3`).

The option listed above works if there is only one subdirectory in `dir-b`, but obviously fails when there are more of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use bash arrays, like:

```
content=(~/dir-a/dir-b/dir-*)     #stores the content of a directory into array "content"
echo "${content[0]}"              #echoes the 1st
echo ${content[${#content[@]}-1]} #echoes the last element of array "comtent"
#or, according to @konsolebox'c comments
echo "${content[@]:(-1)}"
```

Another method, make a bash function like:

```
first() { set "$@"; echo "$1"; }

#and call it
first ~/dir-a/dir-b/dir-*
```

If you want sort files, not by name but by modification time, you can use the next script:

```
where="~/dir-a/dir-b"
find $where -type f -print0 | xargs -0 stat -f "%m %N" | sort -rn | head -1 | cut -f2- -d" "
```

decomposed

- the `find` finds files by defined criteria
- the `xargs` runs the stat command for every found file and prints the result as "modification_time filename"
- the `sort` sorts the result by the time
- the `head` gets the first of them
- and the `cut` cuts the unvanted time field

You can adjust the find with `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` to don't descend deeper.

In linux, it can be shorter, (using -printf format), but this works in OS X too...

Comment: I like this, but how do I get the last directory? I have directories that are named according to versions of a program. I need to get directory  that contains freshest version.

Comment: `echo "${content[@]:(-1)}"` is easier.